# jquery run custom function after another is done

Tags: jquery, callback, wait, deferred

I want to execute a custom function only after the previous custom function is completely done.

I tried with promise, done and when but it's not working correctly. The fisrt function is not completely done when the second is executed...

For example, I want to execute function1() then execute function2 only when function1 is done :

```
function1();
function2();
```

I tried with this but it's not working at all :

```
promise(function1()).done(function2);
```

Here the script of my function1 :

```
function function1() {

    nbofslides = $('.Slide img').length;
    currentslide = 1;

    if ( nbofslides == currentslide) {

        if ( nbofslides > 1) {
            for (i = 1 ; i <= nbofslides ; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    $('.slider-pagination').append('<li class="slider-page selected bgcolor2"></li>');
                } else {
                    $('.slider-pagination').append('<li class="slider-page bgcolor2"></li>');
                }
            }
        }

        $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
            responsiveSlideContainer: true,
            responsiveSlides: true,
            snapToChildren: true,
            desktopClickDrag: true,
            keyboardControls: true,
            infiniteSlider: true,
            navSlideSelector: true,
            autoSlide: false,
            navNextSelector: $('.slider-next'),
            navPrevSelector: $('.slider-prev'),
            navSlideSelector: $('.slider-pagination .slider-page'),
            onSlideChange: slideChange
            });

        var setHeight = $('.iosSlider .Slide:eq(0)').outerHeight(true);
        $('.iosSlider').css({
            height: setHeight
        });

        function slideChange(args) {
        $('.slider-pagination .slider-page').removeClass('selected');
        $('.slider-pagination .slider-page:eq(' + (args.currentSlideNumber - 1) + ')').addClass('selected');
        }

    }
    currentslide++;

}
```

Comment: Do you have an ajax call in your first function ?

Comment: I don't have any asynchronous tasks in function1...

Comment: Can't you just do it like this `-->` `function1();function2();`

Comment: @freaky then you can just do `function1();function2();` and they will run one after the other. My guess is you actually do have something asynchronous going on, otherwise it isn't possible for function2 to start before function1 finishes.

Comment: it can't works like this because it execute function1 then function2 just after. So it don't wait to execute all the script inside function1 before to execute script inside function2 (try with alert() ). It read both function near at the same time .This is the normal behavior of jquery.

Comment: *"This is the normal behavior of **javascript**"*

Comment: @freaky If function1 is not asynchronous, it isn't possible for function2 to begin before function1 finishes, regardless of how much code or how many other functions are executed inside of function1 as long as they are all synchronous as you are describing.

Comment: Maybe it's because of my counter. I've got a counter inside my function1...

Comment: I see nothing in `function1` that would stop you from simply doing `function1();function2();`

Comment: When I put an alert() inside the counter of function1 and an alert inside function2, the function2 alert is trigger before the alert inside function1...

Answer (score 4):

You have to inform function 2 (or something that executes function 2) when function 1 is complete.

```
var deferredObj = $.Deferred();

var function1 = function () {
    ... do some stuff ...
    ... and an ajax request ...
    $.ajax(...).done(function(){
        deferredObj.resolve();
    });
}

deferredObj.done(function(){
    function2();
});
```

However, jQuery makes this even easier by making $.ajax *return* a promise object.

```
var function1 = function() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

function1().done(function2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand how do you write something inside ajax. Success method maybe?

Comment: Why do you need to write something inside ajax? At this point it is very unclear what you are trying to do or what your problem is. Can you please provide more sample code? You first said that you aren't doing anything asynchronous, and now you're talking about ajax. Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: I do a lot of stuff. I have some if condition, some jquery plugin initialization, some css trick and other functions inside it... I think deferred method will be the best way in my case but I never use it before and I think I write it wrong...

Comment: Right.... but that's what we need to see. Something in there is asynchronous if what you are describing is really happening. To be able to call function2 after said asynchronous method finishes, we'll have to know what said method is.

Comment: I don't have asynchronous task inside function1, When I use deferred method it works great with alert, but without it nothing happens

Comment: Provide a working sample. what you are describing isn't possible. If you truely aren't using any asynchronous methods, you don't need deferred objects, promise objects, or even callbacks. Just execute one method after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy one, because most functions don't need any "time" to complete, they just "do a bunch of commands" and after that the next function is called.

In case of JQuery-Animations it runs like that (code by JQuery API)

```
var div = $("div");
div.show("slow");
div.animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
div.slideToggle(1000);
div.slideToggle("fast");
div.animate({left:'-=200'},1500);
...
```

If if we want use animation-queue for our own functions we can use:

```
var div = $("div");
div.show("slow");
div.animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
div.slideToggle(1000);
div.slideToggle("fast");
div.queue(function () {
  alert('We are now at step 4 and if you press OK we go to 5.');
  $(this).dequeue();
});
div.animate({left:'-=200'},1500);
...
```

I hope that's what you are looking for.

If not, keep in mind that jQuery animations have a build-in solution for success-functions:

```
div.animate({left:'-=200'},1500,function(){
  // if animation done, use this code here
});
```

In case you want to delay you commands there is also something for you:

```
div.delay(800).effect("pulsate", {}, 2000).delay(800).queue(someOtherFunction);
```

In that case we would wait 800ms, than use the pulsate-effect (2000ms), wait another 800ms and than startup "someOtherFunction".

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I use function that can't use delay argument. It's not animation... And I always try to avoid waiting time...

Comment: Well, i don't know what you want to do with it. Basicly thats 3 different solutions up there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.button').click(function(){
    if (condition == 'true'){
        function1(someVariable, function() {
          function2(someOtherVariable);
        });
    }
    else {
        doThis(someVariable);
    }
});


function function1(param, callback) {
  ...do stuff
  callback();
```

}